# Should version field be put in edts box or elst box in MP4?

Tags: video, mp4, mp4box

I am trying to learn MP4 Boxes and I saw [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180219054429/http://l.web.umkc.edu/lizhu/teaching/2016sp.video-communication/ref/mp4.pdf) document on the internet. On 8.26 (Page 43), it said that:

> An Edit Box maps the presentation time-line to the media time-line as it is stored in the file. The Edit Box is a container for the edit lists.

> **version** is an integer that specifies the version of this box (0 or 1) 
> **entry_count** is an integer that gives the number of entries in the following table 
> **segment_duration** is an integer that specifies the duration of this edit segment in units of the timescale in the Movie Header Box 
> **media_time** is an integer containing the starting time within the media of this edit segment (in media
> time scale units, in composition time). If this field is set to –1, it is an empty edit. The last edit in a track shall never be an empty edit. Any difference between the duration in the Movie Header Box, and the track’s duration is expressed as an implicit empty edit at the end. 
> **media_rate** specifies the relative rate at which to play the media corresponding to this edit segment. If this value is 0, then the edit is specifying a ‘dwell’: the media at media-time is presented for the segment-duration. Otherwise this field shall contain the value 1.

This is the relationship:

```
edts
|____elst
|____elst
```

As I know, `entry_count` should be put in the `edts` box, but there is a field called `version`, which controls the size of `segment_duration`, `media_time`, and `media_rate`. However, the document did not really clarify where is `version`.

In that case, should the `version` field in `edts` box or in `elst` box?

Answer (score 0):

> *"Should the version field be in the **edts** box or in the **elst** box?"*

It goes in the **elst** box.

**edts** is only 8 bytes. Where it holds 4 bytes for size then 4 bytes for actual text characters of "edts".

The first 4 bytes (SIZE part) means total bytes from the start of text **edts** up to the last byte of the **elst** data(s).

The total then gets a `+4` added to account for length of those starting 4 bytes of SIZE).